# Kivy button binding function with argument

Tags: python, button, arguments, bind, kivy

I am trying to learn how to create application in Kivy and I have problem with sending argument to the function. I want to send text from input to the function and print it. Can somebody tell me how can I do it ?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class TutorialApp(App):
    def gratulation(self, *args):
        print args

    def build(self):
        boxLayout = BoxLayout(spacing=10,orientation='vertical')
        g = TextInput(text='Enter gratulation', 
                      multiline=False,
                      font_size=20,
                      height=100)
        button = Button(text='Send')
        button.bind(on_press=self.gratulation)  

        boxLayout.add_widget(g)
        boxLayout.add_widget(button)
        return boxLayout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TutorialApp().run()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yo must get the text from "g" and then send it to the button callback, there is 2 ways of doing this, by a lambda function, or calling your class method aplying to it.

Lambda Version:

```
from __future__ import print_function ##Need to import this for calling print inside lambda

def build(self):
    boxLayout = BoxLayout(spacing=10,orientation='vertical')
    g = TextInput(text='Enter gratulation', 
                  multiline=False,
                  font_size=20,
                  height=100)
    button = Button(text='Send')
    buttoncallback = lambda:print(g.text)
    button.bind(on_press=buttoncallback)  
    ...
```

The partial version:

```
from functools import partial ##import partial, wich allows to apply arguments to functions returning a funtion with that arguments by default.
def build(self):
    boxLayout = BoxLayout(spacing=10,orientation='vertical')
    g = TextInput(text='Enter gratulation', 
                  multiline=False,
                  font_size=20,
                  height=100)
    button = Button(text='Send')
    buttoncallback = partial(self.gratulation, g.text)
    button.bind(on_press=buttoncallback)  
    ...
```

Comment: Which solution is better (your or his) and why ?

Comment: @AndrewScott i would use lambda version, both of them are ok, they are performing the same operations. Just in case you want to modify behaviour of printing for other calls and keep that behaviour on the button call I would use the partial one, so you can just change your method and it will be preserved on the callback.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class TutorialApp(App):

    def gratulation(self, instance):
        print(self.g.text)

    def build(self):
        boxLayout = BoxLayout(spacing=10,orientation='vertical')
        self.g = TextInput(text='Enter gratulation',
                      multiline=False,
                      font_size=20,
                      height=100)
        button = Button(text='Send')
        button.bind(on_press=self.gratulation)

        boxLayout.add_widget(self.g)
        boxLayout.add_widget(button)
        return boxLayout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TutorialApp().run()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am just beginner, but have I right when am I saying that you add self before attribute "g" and change it to public attribute ?